# Schur-Weyl duality from Double Commutant Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dim complex vector space. Then $V^{\otimes n}$ carries an action by $S_n$ by permuting factors

$\sigma(\pi)(v_1\otimes...\otimes v_n)=v_{\pi^{-1}(1)}\otimes...\otimes v_{\pi^{-1}(n)}$

and an action of GL(V) using the diagonal action of its defining representation $g\in GL(V)$

$\rho(g)(v_1\otimes...\otimes v_n)=gv_1\otimes...\otimes gv_n$

Now we have that if $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\mathbb{C}[S_n])$ then its commutant  is $\mathcal{A'}=\rho(\mathbb{C}[GL(V)])$. Using results from the double commutant theory we get a decomposition of $V^{\otimes n}$ as an $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{A'}-module$.

1) Given that we know the above decomposition how can we argue that we also get a decomposition as an $S_n\times GL(V)-module$?

2) Further, how do we get the decomposition as an $S_n\times U(V)-module$?

The fact that we get all irreducible reps of a group from its group algebra probably plays an important part for 1) but it's not completely clear to me how to go from here to the images of group algebras under the above reps.

Many thanks.

Comment: A version of Schur-Weyl duality is to say $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$ and $\mathbb{C}[GL(V)]$ are each other's commutant, so that gets you (1); that also tells you your algebra is acting on the wrong side.  For (2), what is your $U(V)$? Unitary group?

Comment: Yes U(V) is the unitary group.